# hive syntax error near unexpected token `('

Tags: hadoop, hive

My Hive query has been throwing an error:

> syntax error near unexpected token `('

I am not sure where the error occurs in the query below.

Can you help me out?

```
select 
    A.dataA, B.dataB, count(A.nid), count(B.nid)
from
    (select 
        nid, sum(dataA_count) as dataA
    from
        table_view
    group by nid) A
        LEFT JOIN
    (select 
        nid, sum(dataB_count) as dataB
    from
        table_others
    group by nid) B ON A.nid = B.nid
group by A.dataA , B.dataB;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you didnot close the ) at the end.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes it have been seen that people forget to start the service metastore and thereafter as well as also to enter the hive bash shell, and start passing the commands in similar way of `sqoop`, when I were the newbie I were also facing these things,

so to overcome of this issue -

1. goto the hive directory & pass : `bin/hive --service metastore &` so it will start the hive metastore server for you and later
2. open another terminal or cli & pass : `bin/hive` so it will let you enter inside the hive bash shell.

sometimes when you forgot to do these steps, you got silly issues like on thread title we are discussing here,

hope it will help others, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I have gone through many posts but i didn't realize the my beeline terminal is logged off and i am trying in normal terminal

Answer (score 0):

**I faced an issue exactly like this:**

First, you have opened 6 open parenthesis and 6 closed ones, so this is not your issue.

Last but not least, you are getting this error because your command is getting interpreted word by word. A statement, like a SQL query, is only known for the databases and if you use the language of a specific database, then only that particular database is able to understand it.

Your "before '(' ..." error means, you are using something before the `(` that isnt known for the terminal or the place you are running in.

**All you have to do to fix it is:**

1- Wrap it with a single or double quotation

2- Use where-clause even if you don't need to(for example Apache Sqoop needs it no matter what). So check the documentation for exact way to do so, usually you can use something like `where 1=1` when you dont need it(for Sqoop it was `where $CONDITIONS` .

3- Make sure your command runs in a designated database first, before asking any third party app to run it.

*if this answer was helpful you can give it "chosen answer mark" for better reach in the community.*